# Is it possible to rank the data in following order using SQL ranking functions

Tags: sql, function, ranking

I have data in a table and it needs to be ordered by **Brand** column and ranked as **ClassCode** changes. I have tried using, **ROW_NUMBER, RANK, DENSE_RANK** functions using PARTITION BY but not getting the results I need.

As **ClassCode** changes the rank should be increased and I can't use the **PARTITION BY** for **ClassCode** because it changes the order of Brands.

Example table:

```
Code Brand    ClassCode
101  Sony     201
103  LG       202
104  Nokia    203
107  Sony     201
108  Samsung  202
```

Table data needs to be ordered by **Brand** and ranked by **ClassCode** changes like below:

Required Results:

```
Code Brand    ClassCode  rnk
103  LG       202        1
104  Nokia    203        2
108  Samsung  202        3
101  Sony     201        4
107  Sony     201        4
```

Note: Once I have the order and ranks i need to insert the results into another table. I understand the order by should be done in only SELECT statements but unfortunately the application selects data from a table that has been populated with all the order and ranking logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem, where you are trying to find the number of times the `classcode` changes based on the `code` ordering.

This should return the results you want:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when prev_cc = classcode then 0 else 1 end) over (order by code) as ranking
from (select t.*, lag(classcode) over (order by code) as prev_cc
      from t
     ) t
```

Comment: I have just tried your solution it seems its working however I will need to implement in my complete solution and see the results. Thank you very much for your help and I have learned something new here today called Gaps-and-Islands problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Table data needs to be ordered by Brand and ranked by ClassCode

Ranking and ordering are two different things, that do not *have to* rely on the same set of columns.

You can use the following query to rank by `ClassCode`, and order by `Brand`:

```
select 
    t.*,
    dense_rank() over(order by ClassCode) rnk
from mytable
order by Brand, Code
```

That being said, to generate your expected results, you want to rank by `Brand` (not by `ClassCode`):

```
select 
    t.*,
    dense_rank() over(order by Brand) rnk
from mytable
order by Brand, Code
```

Comment: It does not give me the ranks based on Brand order by.

Comment: @Thiru: the text is your question is quite misleading... Given your expected results, you seem to be looking to rank by `Brand`. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you @GMB. It looks like that solves my issue I will implement that in my solution and let you know.

Comment: @Thiru . . . This doesn't do what you want, based on your sample data.  Code 103 and 108 would have the same value using this logic, but they have different value in your results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, Yes that didn't work in my implementation.